# How can i change a reference to an element in javascript?

Tags: javascript, xml, dom

I would like to modify an element of my xml. I have to query it to find it, and then I only seem to be able to modify a copy of it. I use: `clientXML.querySelector("[id=XMLIssue-9]").childNodes[2].textContent;` to isolate the element in question.
I would like to just replace the element with this one `newXMLIssue.childNodes[0]`. They both have the exact same structure. I cant do:

```
clientXML.querySelector("[id=XMLIssue-9]") = newXMLIssue.childNodes[0];
```

because it causes an error to have the function on the left side of the equation. I also tried:

```
var x = clientXML.querySelector("[id=XMLIssue-9]"); 
x = newXMLIssue.childNodes[0];
```

but this only changes a copy of the element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to call [`replaceChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.replaceChild) on the parent:

```js
var parent = clientXML.querySelector("[id=XMLIssue-9]");

parent.replaceChild(parent.childNodes[0], parent.childNodes[2]);
```